# How to scroll a html scrolling section using input slider and vise versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section which is scrollable in my page and i want to be able to scroll the section with the help of a input slider. If i slide the input slider the section will scroll and also if i scroll on the scrollable section i want the input slider to scroll.

Heres the codepen example where i have created the scrollable section and slider : [`codepen example`](https://codepen.io/JohnTitor1456/pen/JjdxLQX)

I want to acheive this result only using core javascript.

I want to get the currentposition of the scrolling section and then convert it to percentage and link it to the input slider. The value of input slider ranges from 0 to 100 so i thought that this might be achievable that way. Then when we slide the input slider, it changes the scrollposition of the scrolling section accordingly. The final result should be that whether you slide the slider or scroll on the scrolling section itself both of them scrolls consecutively.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem needs to be placed directly in your question, in text form & properly formatted, or as an executable Stack Snippet, in cases where that makes sense. _Do not_ just dump it all onto an external platform only. Please edit your qestion accordingly.

Comment: _“I want to acheive this result only using core javascript.”_ - then you still need to start writing it. This here is not a code-writing service. We can help with problems with code you _have_ written, but this is not the place to ask that someone do the whole thing _for you_.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stack overflow and also english is not my primary language but I am asking here for ideas on how this is achievable not the whole code on how to do this.

Comment: What i have thought here on the javascript part is first i am going to calculate the height of the scroll section and then the scrolltop of the section. Then convert it into percentage when the user scrolls on the section. After that i am confused on how i am going to link this percentage to that of the input slider. I hope I made myself clear here.

Comment: Please first of all edit your question as advised nonetheless. (Code into the question, not just external on codepen.) _“What i have thought here on the javascript part is first i am going to calculate the height of the scroll section and then the scrolltop of the section.”_ - then try and transform these thoughts into code, please, and show the result.

Comment: Yes i will soon get into this. Currently i am busy with tight schedule and deadlines. Once i am free i will upload the code itself. Also sorry i thought using external codepen would be easier but i understand now and  i will upload the code here itself. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

This is all of the code that i made. It should work.

```js
function something() {
  var test = document.getElementById("slideScroll").value;
  document.getElementById("scrollingSection").style.top = test + "px";
}
setInterval(something, 1)
```

```css
.second-section {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20%;
  background: #d2d2d2;
}

.scrollslider {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)rotate(90deg);
}

.slider-scroll {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #030303;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.95;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider-scroll:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-scroll::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #a1a1a1;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-scroll::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffc800;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollable-section {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

#scrollingSection::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#scrollingSection {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-section">
  <p>Lorem ipsum Loreum ipsum<br>Lorem ipsum Loreum ipsum<br></p>
</div>
<div class="second-section">
  <div class="scrollslider">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider-scroll" id="slideScroll">
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-section" id="scrollingSection" style="position:absolute;top:30px">
    <div class="scrollable-section" id="scrollingSection">
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dummydiv">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-section">
    <p>Lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
```

The JS part is basically getting the Slider value and adding it to the top:10px; value. When you drag it down, it goes down. When you drag it up it goes up.

Comment: Thanks for your help and instant reply but i am sorry this is not the way i want to acheive this. Maybe i was not clear on the question part but I want to be able to do this without doing anything to the position of the section. I want to do this by getting the scroll position of the section and convert it to percent then link it to the value of the input slider. The value of input slider ranges from 0 to 100 so i thought it would be possible to achevie it that way.

Comment: I am sorry but this did not help me . Is there any possible way to do it like the way i mentioned avobe in the question.

Comment: Sorry, That's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks very much if things doesnt work out ill try this out.